# When I install Salt on OS X, cannot find configuration file

Tags: macos, installation, configuration-files, salt-stack

I am new to Salt, just want to install it on my MacBook for work. 
I follow the instructions in https://salt.readthedocs.org/en/v0.16.4/topics/installation/osx.html

When I move the the step **Salt-Master Customizations**, I find I cannot find the configuration file.
I go to directory **/etc/salt** via **Finder** and only find one directory **pki**.

From http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/examples.html#configuration-examples-master, it provides a sample configuration file. Then I am not sure what to do next? Do I need to create a configuration file under the directory of **/etc/salt**? If so, how to name the configuration file? Name it as **master.conf**?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file as:

`/etc/salt/master`

and add the sample configuration file you have found. More details can be found on the configuration page here: [Configuring Salt](https://salt.readthedocs.org/en/v0.16.4/topics/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks! I tried. In the directory /etc/salt, I copy the configuration file from http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/examples.html#configuration-examples-master and paste to a new file which is named as **master**. Still report  ''[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /etc/salt/master ''

Comment: can you post the exact output of 'ls -la /etc/salt'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `-c /path/to/config/dir/`  when starting the master?